# UITableViewHeaderFooterView remove transparency

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've done some searching, and a lot of answers are saying that I need to create a custom `UIView` and stick it in to the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`.

At the moment, I'm setting the appearance in the AppDelegate like so

```
   [[UITableViewHeaderFooterView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

But I want to get rid of the transparency. Is there a way to do this from the appDelegate without having to go through my entire app and change the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` wherever a tableView is being used?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` sets the `backgroundColor` of its `backgroundView` to a slightly transparent version of its `tintColor`.

As a workaround, you can set the `backgroundColor` of any subview of the  `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`.

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class], nil] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can now accomplish this in Swift by implementing the `tableView( willDisplayHeaderView:forSection)` delegate method and overriding the `backgroundColor` of the `backgroundConfiguration` like so:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    guard let headerFooter = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView else {
        return
    }
        
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        headerFooter.backgroundConfiguration?.backgroundColor = .white // put here your color
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }           
}
```

`headerFooter`'s UILabel is accessible via `headerFooter.textLabel?` if you would also like to customize the header/footer's font, color, etc.

Comment: This code works only if you have iOS 14 or +